# Issue with onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview

I am creating an app, On app start camera opens to take pic. I have also implemented the Facebook login in the app [FB Login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/), everything is working fine. My problem is I want to show the pic taken in an imageView which I have added in the MainActivity layout. There is no error but image is not showing in imageView. But when I change the name of onActivityResult method to onActivityResult2 image doesn't display. Image displays when I dont change method name. I can't keep the name to onActivityResult because in another class this method is handling the Facebook Login. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone help me out. Here is my complete code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private MainFragment mainFragment;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private ImageView imageView;
private Button btn_up, btn_new;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
    mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();

} else {
    // Or set the fragment from restored state info
    mainFragment = (MainFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);

}
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imview);

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);


}
protected void onActivityResult1(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
  if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
      Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
      imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
  }  
} 
}
```

And following is my Fragment Class

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = "MainFragment";
private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
public Bitmap photo;
private int RESULT_OK = 1;
private ImageView imageView;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
private Button btn_up, btn_new;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    LoginButton authButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.authButton);
    authButton.setFragment(this);
    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imview);
    btn_new = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_new);

    btn_up = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_up);
    btn_new.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
public void onActivityResult1(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
      if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  
          Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
          imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
      }
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (state.isOpened()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        //LoginButton aButton


    } else if (state.isClosed()) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");

    }
}
private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null &&
           (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed()) ) {
        onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
    }

    uiHelper.onResume();

}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //authButton.setFragment(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try loading the bitmap by the Uri you receive. "data" will not always be filled out.  `Bitmap bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), data.getData());`

Comment: I think that wont be the problem, because I was using this before an image was loading correctly in ImageView. It happened when I changed the name of `onActivityResult()` method

Comment: Don't change name of it. It expects the name to be onActivityResult. You use the request code to differentiate between requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, actually it's quite normal your `onActivityResult1()` isn't called at all, because the start-for-result pattern need that specific function signature in order to work properly. All you need is to:

- rename back `MainActivity.onActivityResult1(...)` method in `MainActivity.onActivityResult(...)`
- delete `MainFragment.onActivityResult1(...)` method and make the `MainFragment.onActivityResult(...)` look like this:

.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 
    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
  }
  else
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: this handles correctly when I take picture from button click (in MainFragment class). But it doesn't work when app start camera opens and it takes picture. And I now understood the proper use of onActivityResult(); method. Thanks for that.

Comment: Actually when you invoke `startActivityForResult(...)` you should provide a request code exactly to ease the result detection :) I'm glad it helped. BTW I still can't understand what doesn't work.

Comment: I tell what is not working. I open camera in two ways. (1) When app starts. And (2) In main layout I have button of take new, when click on that. For second option I am opening the camera and taking the pic and showing in ImageView working fine. For option one camera opens take pic but doesn't load in ImageView. Hope you understand now.

Comment: Oh yes, now i got it. So you should not delete `onActivityResult1(...)` from your Activity, but simply rename it into `onActivityResult(...)`. Sorry for that, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Only one little problem and that is the previous image remains loaded when new taken and new doesn't show in ImageView instead the image that is captured first remains in ImageView. Should I make imageView null before setting bitmap into it??

Comment: Well, not imageView itself actually, maybe its source. But it's not strictly related to your initial question.

Comment: Infact, It is related to the question. That should be the scenario of working. I tried 3 methods .. `invalidate() , setImageBitmap(null) and setImageResource(0)` all three didn't work. what else can be done. I am really appcreciating your help .

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh, but if you are sure `onActivityResult` is invoked properly in both `MainActivity` and `MainFragment`, then you should consider the problem solved and mark this answer as accepted. BTW if you need further help you can join me here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25245/question-15119330

Comment: nadeem gc is right, the imageview doesn't update in this scenario, I'm facing the same issue. It shouldn't be marked complete because the original issue is that the imageview doesn't display, and it still doesn't.

Comment: I have the same problem, my image path is hard coded, but it won't display inside the image view...:(