# Removing image from ImageView and load new Image

Tags: android, imageview

I am facing problem on removing image from `ImageView`. 
What I want an Image is loaded in `ImageView`, and then a new Image is taken by the camera and now that Image should load in `ImageView` replacing the previous one. I have tried

1. `invalidate();`
2. `setImageBitmap(null);`
3. `setImageResource(0);`

All these 3 methods are not working. Can someone help me.

Comment: Simply add the new image and it should override the old one, have you tried that?

Comment: yea i have tried that.

Comment: new Image I am setting from the other class.

Comment: What exactly happens? do you get error? or the new image does not show up? post your code

Comment: I dont get any error. Image just dont shows up.

Comment: I have posted the complete code in my previous question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15119330/issue-with-onactivityresult).

Comment: Are you getting it properly from resources?

Comment: I am taking picture from camera and, loading captured image in ImageView. both time I am doing this

Answer (score 0):

Use this for setting image in ImageView

```
image.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to set the Image By Drawable Image you can use like this

  ```
  your_image_view.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(your_drawable_Image_id));
  ```
- If you want to set the image by BitMapDrawable

  ```
  your_image_view.setBackgroundDrawable(your_drawable_bitmap);
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
edit_countflag.setBackgroundColor(0);
edit_countflag.setImageResource(R.drawable.flag_id);
```